# javascript MIME type not executable

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working to fix the following error in my application

**"Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/jquery-1.10.2.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."** (login page of app)(same error for css file also)

but this error occurs **only when the application is opened for the first time** in the browser. Once I proceed to login and then come back to the login page again, the error does not occur. Any idea why this might happen?
(have tried testing in different browsers. app responds in same way).

Comment: Can you show us how are you including the script in your page?

Comment: open up the url in the browser and see. My guess is it is an html page. Sounds like the server has a very generic redirect rule.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/js/bootstrap1.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
<script src="/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login1.css"/>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/login1.js"> </script>                  This is how I added the script, The js and css are put in the static folder of Springboot project